# Are there any Wild Shape forms that have both a knockdown and multiattack?

Tags: dnd-5e, wild-shape, animals

Fifth Edition. Are there any creatures that would be a valid target for a Druid Wild Shape that also fulfill the following requirements?

- A knock-prone effect on one of its attacks
- Multiattack

For examples of a knock-prone effect, see a wolf's Bite attack, or a Tiger's Pounce ability.

The combo I'm looking for is to make an attack with a knock-prone effect (dealing damage and knocking the target prone) and then use my second attack to grapple them (preventing them from standing). I'm aware that you can do this using Shove and Grapple for any form with multiattack, but I'm looking for a way to do that combo and still deal damage that turn.

Answer (score 10):

You can't grapple this way.

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it,
>   you can **use the Attack action** to make a special melee
>   attack, a grapple. If you’re able to make multiple attacks
>   with **the Attack action**, this attack replaces one of them.

To substitute a grapple for one of your attacks, you have to be taking the Attack action. The Multiattack action can't be used for this.

Comment: Well, I was wrong: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/11/19/multiattack-and-grapple/

Answer (score 5):

## This does not work

[Sage's Advice says](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/11/19/multiattack-and-grapple/) possible parts of the Multiattack are always listed, and shove is usually not in the list.

## What you can do instead

Restraining is equal in most ways, better in some.

Similar:

- Target's speed is 0
- You get advantage against the target
- The target attacks with disadvantage
- You only get to make one damaging attack

Better

- No second roll is necessary, if you hit, the target is restrained
- Even your ranged party members get advantage agains the victim

The only possible advantage grapple+prone might have over restrained is that if the victim frees itself, half of its speed must be spent on getting up, so it can't run that far away.
Even in this case a restraining shape is better, if the target tries to run away you get one attack. You can use the same restraining one, so it will provide advantage again.

### Shapes that provide restraining attacks

- CR1: Giant Octopus, Giant Toad
- CR2: Giant Constrictor Snake
- CR5: Giant Crocodile

Comment: Worth pointing out that despite that website's name, developer tweets are not Sage Advice (that is an article series and compendium published on WotC's website).